# system bootOrder not found on Lenovo T540

Tags: 18.04, uefi, lenovo, bios

Upgraded my Ubuntu (with dual boot Windows) to 18.04 . After restart I got "System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults." . Changing the BIOS bootorder to Windows as 1st works, of course, but i want my dual boot option back. 
I tried the same solution as an Acer user had ("I switched "secure boot"on"). But I don't get the option of "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" . Where can I activate those UEFI files, in the BIOS???

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change the defaults, You are using Grub2 as your bootloader. in this case, please use this command to reconfigure your grub configs.

I assume that `os-prober` and `efibootmgr` are installed by default, so:

`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

It will create new `grub.cfg` file. now reboot your system.
Let me know if it solve your problem or not.

Comment: Thanks Hamid. I'll first make a USB with ubuntu to boot, so I am able to enter a command... I'll get back to you when I tried it.

Comment: I tried Linux Mint for a change on the USB, to be able to create that new grub file:    mint@mint:~$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root
mint@mint:~$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
So... is that file supposed to be in the BIOS or on the HDD... and will it go to the USB HDD when I try this?

Comment: For running `grub-mkconfig` for a broken grub on a system, you must first `mount` necessary partitions like `EFI`, `boot` partition (if it is separated) and `root` to the booted system (somewhere like your current `/mnt`). then use `chroot` to enter into `/mnt` that you mounted the broken OS. then you can simply run `grub-mkconfig` as a root as I shared before.

Comment: Finally started to study the subject of bootloaders on: https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html

Comment: Nixie helped me with the mounting part... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I

Comment: "system bootorder not found. Initializing defaults. Creating boot entry "Boot0018" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"   Reset System

Comment: http://adityagilra.blogspot.com/2014/11/fixing-ubuntu-boot-problems-with-boot.html

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9GXDmVMH3b/

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: The Boot-repair tool tells me to turn off "secure boot".... confused now...