# Ubuntu 19.10 - System BootOrder Not Found Initializing Default. HP Elitebook 8570w

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, hp, 19.10

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my laptop. the installation was successful. but when I turn on my laptop it shows `System BootOrder Not Found Initializing Default` for a while then boots into ubuntu. I have a UEFI Bios with GPT SSD.

My system information:

- [HP Elitebook 8570w](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/workstations/images/datasheet_8570w.pdf)
- Nvidia Quadro k1000m
- 250 GB SSD

What I've tried:

1. I have installed boot repair on live and ran recommended repair.
2. Ran: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` from another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071745/system-bootorder-not-found-on-lenovo-t540).

I have seen another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found) talking about custom boot and defining some paths. I don't have a custom boot option in my bios instead I have customized boot which is checked by default and I don't see any option to add any path there.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL as of now.

Answer (score 1):

On my HP EliteBook Folio 1020 G1, there is no option to choose a trusted UEFI file.

However, there is an option for "custom boot" under the "boot options" menu.

Add a custom boot path and enter `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`. It must be a backslash `\`, and **not** a slash `/`.

Then put "custom boot" on top of the boot priority list.

Save and reboot.